# How do functions from a header file get linked to the .c file?

Tags: c, header-files, cs50

In problem set 4 of `cs50`, there is a main function `filter.c`, which uses header file `helper.h`. The latter contains the prototypes of a few functions, and these complete functions are written out in `helper.c`

My question is: since `filter.c` only connects to `helper.h`, how does it connect to the code of the functions? Or does filter.c automatically also look for a .c file with the same name as the linked header file?

I hope this is somewhat clear!

Comment: When the final executable is built it will "link" in both `filter.o` and `helper.o`.

Answer (score 3):

The compilation of a `C` program involves three basic steps listed below shortly:

#### Preprocessing:

the preprocessor takes a `C` source code file and deals with the `#includes`, `#defines` and other preprocessor `directives`. also clean all the comments and expand all the macros in those files. (it performs both on c and h files) The output of this step is a `"pure"` `C` file without pre-processor directives.

#### Compilation:

the compiler takes the pre-processor's output and produces an object file from it. written in assembly that suits the cpu your code will run on it.

#### Linking:

the linker takes the object files produced by the compiler and produces either a library or an executable file. which have all the information and a process terms to be run directly by the os (.out or .elf are examples of the linker output).

#### your case

In `filter.c` or in each `.c` file (including the `helper.c`), where you `#includes "helper.h"`, this step ended with all functions signature declared in `helper.h` copy paced in `filter.c` (**only signatures**). now this happen in `preprocessor time`. now in `main.c` where (i suppose) you `#includes "filter.h"`, the preprocessor will copy all the **nested** `.h` files (tell reaching last `.h` file in the chain) into `main.c` (in our case its only `filter.h` that contains the `helper.h`). when `compiler` comes to compile the `.c` files, he compiles `helper.c`, `'filter.c` and `main.c` and generates object files (`.o`  or `.obj` - binary files suited for current cpu) at end he triggers the linker to link all these `objects` together to become and fully executable (linker also links all functions that came from predefined libs like printf for e.g.)

```
                 preprocessor                    compiler                 linker
                 ------------                    --------                 --------
+------------+ copy helper.h to    +----------+         
+  helper.h  +------------------>  + filter.c + -------> filter.o +      +--------+
+------------+        |            +----------+                   |      +        +
                      |                                           |      + .elf   +
                      |                                           +--->  +        +
                      +--------->  +-----------+                         +  or    +
                                   + helper.c  + ------> helper.o ---->  + .out   +
                                   +-----------+                  +--->  +--------+
                                                                  |          ^
        +-------------+                                           |          |
        + filter.h    +---------> +-------------+                 |          |
        +-------------+           + main.c      + -----> main.o---+          | 
                                  +-------------+                            |  
                                                                             |
                                                         +-------------------+
                                                         + libs (e.g. stdio) +
                                                         +-------------------+
```